# Executing adb commands on Android 10 (API 29)

Tags: android, kotlin, adb, android-10.0

I'm trying to run adb commands programmatically from inside an Android priviledged app (apk file uploaded to `priv-app` folder, `privapp-permissions-platform.xml` file uploaded to `/etc/permissions/`.

```
private fun executeAdbCommand() {
    val commandStart = "am start -n com.abc.bcd/com.abc.bcd.MainActivity"
    val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandStart)
    val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(process.inputStream))
        
    val commandBattery = "dumpsys battery set level 20"
    val processBattery = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandBattery)
    val bufferedReaderBattery = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(processBattery.inputStream))

    val commandBack = "input keyevent ${KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK}"
    val processBack = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandBack)
    val bufferedReaderThree = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(processBack.inputStream))
}
```

The first two commands produce no result. The third one is actually pressing the Back Button.
When I run the first two commands from a PowerShell windows they are both executed correctly:
`adb shell am start -n com.abc.bcd/com.abc.bcd.MainActivity` is starting the mentioned activity,
`adb shell dumpsys battery set level 20` is setting the emulator's battery to 20%.

I am targeting Android 10 (API level 29) - is this the expected behaviour of the system? What is the particular reason the first two commands are getting discarded (no error log is generated) and the third one is getting executed? Is there any way of getting the first two commands running (might this be a missing permission or something similar)?

Comment: You have to catch/intercept STDOUT/ERR for each command or it's difficult to understand why it has that behaviour...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @emandt - I've logged the stdout/err in AS logcat but no meaningful info was logged.